# Firefox 'Open new tab' on JTabbedPane

Tags: swing, firefox, jtabbedpane

I want to add a button to JTabbedPane's title bar (similar to the 'open new tab' ('+') button in Firefox) 
I have tried to add to the glass pane of JTabbedPane's container. but since my tabbedpane contains within a JPanel seems it doesn't work for me. 
Any suggestion will be a great help for me.
Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971141/java-add-tab-button-for-a-jtabbedpane/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of adding a button I have tried it in a different way and worked for me... I have added a JLabel (with '+') as a hidden tab and when user tries to select that tab i'll be adding a new tab.

```
public class AddTabButtonDemo extends JFrame{

private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

public AddTabButtonDemo() {
    JLabel tab1Label = new JLabel("tab1");
    JPanel tab1 = new JPanel();
    tab1.add(tab1Label);
    tabbedPane.addTab("tab1", tab1);
    tabbedPane.addTab("+", new JLabel());
    tabbedPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent() instanceof JLabel) {
                int count = tabbedPane.getTabCount();
                JLabel newTabLabel = new JLabel("tab" + count);
                JPanel newTab = new JPanel();
                newTab.add(newTabLabel);
                tabbedPane.add(newTab, count - 1);
                tabbedPane.setTitleAt(count - 1, "tab" + count);
                tabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(newTab);
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    this.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AddTabButtonDemo();
}

}
```